# Title Image stretching too much in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationitem

Currently I'm trying to set a title image for my UINavigationBar, but it's stretching quite wide. I'm using the following code:

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 20.0f);
    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"titleImage.png"]];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = myImage;
```

Does anybody have an idea as to why it's stretching so much **width wise**?

Comment: First you should be clear with your question, whether to put image in title view or in navigation bar

Comment: @kirtiavaiya self.navigationItem.titleView...doesn't get clearer than that.

Comment: @kirtiavaiya did you read the code?

Comment: @ A user , you wrote your code wrong first thats the problem..

Comment: @kirtiavaiya your a nugget haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try setting the contentMode on either the navigationItem or the UIImageView?

```
myImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeAspectFill;
```

Comment: this seems to work, but my image is still pixelated. Can I ask a related question: what size should I make my title image for a retina display? Currently I have a 360x90 pixel image. This is 3 times a 90x30 image which is what I thought would be a good size for a titleview. Any thoughts?

Comment: anything larger than the actual view shouldn't pixelate when scaled down, so it must be trying to scale it up. Normally for a 90 x 30 image you would want a 180 x 60 image for retina screens (@2x.png). Maybe it isn't picking up the retina assets so its using the non-retina assets?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use following code it will set image to center of navigationbar..

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sclogo.png"];
      self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set image in full navigation bar than you can use follwoing code :-

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youimage"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You are trying to set image in navigation bar title view.

Comment: This sets the background image for the navigation bar. I'm trying to use an image as the title in a specific view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```